# Add shipping cost to a Monthly PaymentPlan

Tags: api, paypal, nvp

I'm wondering if it's possible to add a shipping cost to a Monthly Payment Plan. I'm using the PayPal API NVP and I have it working successfully for the Buyitnow button. I know this Website Standards HTML Variables page states that the shipping is only available for the Buyitnow and Addtocart buttons. Go to the developer site of PayPal and append the URL. I don't have enough points to submit a URL yet.

/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#id08A6HI00JQU

But the PayPal API NVP page has a different variable:

L_OPTIONnSHIPPINGAMOUNTx - (Optional) The shipping amount to bill for the cycle, in addition to the base amount. It is a list of variables for each OPTION0NAME, in which x is a digit between 0 and 4, inclusive

The option variables work such as:

```
OPTION0NAME="Standard Package Services"
L_OPTION0SELECT0="3 Monthly Payments"
OPTION0TYPE="EMI"
L_OPTION0AMOUNT0="897"
L_OPTION0BILLINGFREQUENCY0="1"
L_OPTION0BILLINGPERIOD0="Month"
L_OPTION0TOTALBILLINGCYCLES0="3"
```

All the above options work but the shipping variable "L_OPTION0SHIPPINGAMOUNT0" does not work. Why does it not work?

```
L_OPTION0SHIPPINGAMOUNT0="19"
```

Here is the PayPal API NVP doc page. Append the URL to the developer PayPal site:

/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/button-manager/BMCreateButton_API_Operation_NVP/

The PayPal API NVP doc does not state if the shipping option (L_OPTIONnSHIPPINGAMOUNTx) is only available for the Buyitnow and Addtocart buttons though. Can it work for the PaymentPlan buttons too?

I hope someone knows the answer here too though. I've posted to http://paypal.com/mts and created a ticket.

Comment: Ok, just heard back from Paypal.com/mts.

Just quoting their response:

---

Hi Victor,

Thanks for reverting.

The button manager api are there only to create the button dynamically using the code but it doesn't modify the behavior for the standard payapl buttons . Meaning even if you create the buttons thru the api the button behaviour will remain same and since you have created the subscription button so all the rules defined on the standard html variable page will apply to button created thru the api also.

Do revert me in case any further clarifications. 

---- 
I hope this helps others!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [Express Checkout API](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/overview-ec.pdf) and include the shipping parameters available in the [CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/) request.

If you're working with PHP you may want to check out my [class library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/download-angell-eye-php-class-library-for-paypal/).  It would make setting up Express Checkout with recurring payments very quick and easy for you.

Comment: Thank you, Andrew! I'm just wondering if you're still updating that class and it's still good for any of the latest Paypal functionality. I'm beginning to implement Laravel too. Do you have some Laravel packages for the Paypal?

Comment: I don't have a specific package for Laravel, but the class library I linked you to is available on Packagist so you can easily add it with Composer.  In fact, I have this http://paypal-glass.angelleye.com project I started where I'm using Laravel with my class library to replicate the PayPal user interface, just to show off all the different things my library can do.  And yes, I still maintain this thing and keep it up to date with PayPal's API, so no worries there.  That PayPal Glass tool is available on GitHub if you're interested: https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-glass

Comment: Oh, thanks, Andrew! Wow! So awesome. Will definitely check it out later. God bless your day!<><